# Performance enhancement for API

Tags: node.js, performance, google-cloud-platform

I have developed an API for a customer and we expect a huge amount of users. The main API endpoint that everyone will go through is /create-program as it creates a fitness program for a user. It is a very complex algorithm and it takes about 1.5 - 2.5 to create a program. When deployed to GCP Cloud Run and tested with k6 50 VUs for 10 seconds it works super slow taking around 10-20 seconds on average. We expect to have 10k users in the first month. Also, sometimes I have this error in the GCP logs

> node:13) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added to [Connection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit...

I would appreciate any help and advice if this indicates that we need to speed up the algorithm, fix something on GCP, or move to another plan/hosting service. Please ask for any additional information.

My cloud run config

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider doing a partial response,  for better performance, you can ask the server to send only the fields you really need and get a partial response instead.

Attaching here the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#partial) as reference.

Comment: seems like a good thing to use, thanks!